# onPress not running on navigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have made a bottom navigator component but cant figure out why its not working. My other onPress handlers work as expected.

This is the navigator that is giving me issues

```
export default function App(){

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TabNavigator/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )

}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function TabNavigator(){
  return(
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName={"Dashboard"} backBehavior={"initialRoute"} tabBar={(props)=> <TabBar {...props}/>}>
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Dashboard" 
          component={DashboardScreen}
          initialParams={{
            icon: 'dashboard'
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Habits" 
          component={HabitsScreen} 
          initialParams={{
            icon: 'addchart'
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen 
          name="Profile" 
          component={ProfileScreen} 
          initialParams={{
            icon: 'account-circle'
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
  )

}


function TabBar({state, navigation}){
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('Dashboard')

  function renderColor(routeName){return  routeName == selected ? 'red' : 'grey'}

  function handlePress(routeName){ 
    if(routeName !== selected){
      navigation.navigate(routeName)
      setSelected(routeName) 
    }
  }

  const {routes} = state;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {
          routes.map(route => {
            return (
              <TabItem
              tab={route}
              handlePress={handlePress}
              color={renderColor(route.name)}
              key={route.key}
              />
            )

          })
        }
    </View>
  )

}


function TabItem({tab,color, handlePress}){
  return(

    <View style={{alignItems:'center'}} onPress={()=> {
      console.log('pressed');
      handlePress(tab.name)
    }}>
      <MaterialIcons name={tab.params.icon} size={24} color={color} />
      <Text style={{color}}>{tab.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

I have multiple other onPress handlers and they do work as expected but this was does not.
Has anyone encountered this? What did you do?

Answer (score 0):

I had the onPress on a view component, Turns out they dont allow onPress, Instead i used a TouchableOpacity